# WPF databinding from DataTemplate - many-to-many relationship

Tags: wpf, many-to-many, datatemplate

I have a WPF control for laying out items and set `ItemsSource` for it as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding item_portfolio}" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

In the layout control's Resources I set the template for its items:

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding portfolio.PortfolioName}"  />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ?}">
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The data for the bindings is a many-to-many relationship (one item can have many portfolios and one portfolio can have many items) and specified in 3 separate tables in the database (I use Entity Framework to access it). Schema and example data below:

```
item               item_portfolio                   portfolio
ID (PK)  Name      itemID (FK)  portfolioID (FK)    ID  PortfolioName
1        Item 1       1               1             1   Portfolio 1
2        Item 2       1               2             2   Portfolio 2
                      1               3             3   Portfolio 3
                      2               2
                      2               3
```

`TextBlock` binding under `DataTemplate` works correctly. 
I don't however know how to bind the `ListView` `ItemsSource` so that it would show all the item objects belonging to that portfolio.

Edit:
I want to list portfolios in the layout control. Then under portfolio, I want to show what items it contains. The below image shows the UI when the SelectedItem is Item 1.

[image]

(First I show what portfolios this item has. This gives 3 portfolios. This works ok. Then on UI I click the portfolio 3, and it should show all items (Item 1 and Item 2) belonging to that portfolio. That doesn't work yet.)

Answer (score 0):

We don't model our data models in code in the same way as they are modelled in the database. We don't make 'joining classes' to model 'joining tables'. Instead, we create hierarchical data models. In your case, you should have an `Item` class that has a `Portfolio` property of type `Portfolio`. There should be no `ItemPortfolio` class, as it makes no sense. Then, your `Binding` should be this`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

Then your `DataTemplate` (which will automatically have its `DataContext` set to an item from the `Item` class collection) should look more like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PortfolioName}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Portfolio}">
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Clearly, to make this work, you'd need to have those properties defined in your `Item` class.

---

UPDATE >>>

In that case, make a `Portfolio` class with an `Items` property of type `ObservableCollection<Item>` and set the `ItemsSource` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Portfolios}" ... />
```

To clarify, your `Item` class should also have a collection property of type `ObservableCollection<Portfolio>`... this *will* lead to some data object duplication, but in WPF it is more important to provide your views with the data that they require.

Comment: In my item.item_portfolio binding the item_portfolio is a entity framwork Navigation Property. This middle table should be dropped off as a class (as you mentioned) but for some reason Entity Framework did not do so when creating the model from database although its a many-to-many relationship between item and portfolio.

Comment: I don't think I want to bind to list of items. Instead I want to bind to list of portfolios. Updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Expander control** here as you want PortfolioName as header and on click of
 PortfolioName you want to display corresponding PortfolioItemList.

**xaml code**

```
<ItemsControl  MaxHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding PortfolioInfo}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Background="YellowGreen" Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"></ListBox>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**C# code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Portfolio> PortfolioInfo { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PortfolioInfo = new ObservableCollection<Portfolio>()
        {
            new Portfolio(){name="Portfolio1", ItemList= new List<string>(){"Item1","Item2","Item3"}},
            new Portfolio(){name="Portfolio2", ItemList= new List<string>(){"Item1","Item2","Item3"}},
            new Portfolio(){name="Portfolio3", ItemList= new List<string>(){"Item1","Item2","Item3"}}                             
        };
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
public class Portfolio
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

**Note** : Edit [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.110).aspx) style/template to achieve desired UI

**Rseult**

[image]